# Expand the incomplete gamma function $\int_0^x e^{-t}t^n dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

Expand the incomplete gamma function $\int_0^x e^{-t}t^n dt$ in a series of powers of x.

What I have tried:

I know the expansions:  $$t^n = 1 + t + t^2+\cdots+t^n \\
e^{-t} = 1-t+\frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots+\frac{(-1)^nt^n}{n!}$$
Combining this into the integral
$$\int_0^x \left(1-t+\frac{t^2}{2!} + \cdots+\frac{(-1)^nt^n}{n!} \right) \left(1 + t + t^2+\cdots+t^n \right)dt$$

I'm not sure if this step is allowed, but I integrated as is:
$$\int_0^x e^{-t}t^n dt = \left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots+\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \right) \left(x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \right)$$

How do I simplify this even further?

Comment: Why $t^n=1+t+...+t^n$?  It is wrong!  Also $e^{-t}$ expansion has upper limit $n= \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but what you wrote is wrong under many respects.

1. You cannot truncate $e^{-t}$
2. $t^n\ne 1+t+\dots+t^n$

You can instead expand
$$
t^ne^{-t}=t^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^k}{k!}=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^{k+n}}{k!}
$$
Integrating term by term from $0$ to $x$, we get
$$
\int_0^x t^ne^{-t}\,dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{k+n+1}}{(n+k+1)k!}
$$